# проблема в создание новых страниц

Tags: php

проблема в создание новых страниц вылетает такая ошибка Warning: file_get_contents([https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=8331fb3a-dd1d-47a5-a76d-c36b0a94faf7&geocode=Тюмень](https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=8331fb3a-dd1d-47a5-a76d-c36b0a94faf7&geocode=%D0%A2%D1%8E%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C)): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: ссылка работает, как видно. опишите детали что-ли какие-то. Прочите апи геокодера, в каких случаях он возвращает 403

Comment: если вы только что зарегали ключ, то в документации указано, что он не сию-минутно активируется

Comment: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/reference/error_codes.html в документации указано что 403 при невалидном ключе. вероятно ваш на момент попытки использования еще не был активирован.

Answer (score 0):

Как говорит документация :

> Код ответа на статус ошибки "HTTP 403 Forbidden" указывает, что сервер понял запрос, но отказывается его авторизовать.

Соответственно, Вас отказывается авторизовать сервер.

Значит, уточняем у [документации Яндекс Карт](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/reference/error_codes.html)

И видим:

> В запросе используется невалидный API-ключ. Убедитесь, что вы используете правильный API-ключ. Проверить актуальность ключа можно в кабинете разработчика

Соответственно, либо не указан API-key, либо какой-то из параметров.

Для уточнения ошибки добавьте в запрос `?format=json` и сервер вернёт json с описанием, что пошло не так.